# I want to select a specific td via javascript for want to put there some class

Tags: javascript

I didn't make any HTML for that, create a table via javascript. Here is the code:

```
<code>
var container = document.createElement("div");
    var col_sm_12 = document.createElement("div");
    var tables = document.createElement("table");
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
    tables.id = "first_table";
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j <= 5; j++){
            var column = document.createElement("td");
            var columntext = document.createTextNode("Hello " + j);
            column.appendChild(columntext);
            tr.appendChild(column);
            }
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        }

    container.className = "container";
    col_sm_12.className = "col-sm-12";
    tables.className = "table table-bordered table-striped";
    container.appendChild(col_sm_12);
    col_sm_12.appendChild(tables);
    tables.appendChild(tbody);
    document.body.appendChild(container);   
</code>
```

Kindly Help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which part is not working??

Comment: everything is working fine, but i want to add a class with some specific td like row no. 2 column no. 4

Comment: simply `if (i === 2 && j === 4) { column.className = 'className'; }`

Comment: @ahmad its not working.

Comment: @AbhishekAnand check this https://jsfiddle.net/zr0d723u/

Comment: thanks for your help @ahmed, m new in javascript ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (for td no. 2 or 4):

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j <= 5; j++){
        var column = document.createElement("td");
        var columntext = document.createTextNode("Hello " + j);
        if(j == 2 || j == 4){
            column.setAttribute('class','some-classes');
        }
        column.appendChild(columntext);
        tr.appendChild(column);
        }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: showing error in console :(

Comment: Don't answer dupes.

Comment: Thanks MHS, its working fine, actually you wrote or instead of || that's why showing some error.